# How do I do this join in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following

```
a Category - belongs_to :item
a Item - has_one :category
```

Item has a category_id. How do I write a query to produce summary which includes a count of items with each category ?

```
CategoryA - 15
CategoryB - 20
CategoryC - 25
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your association is setup wrongly. It should be

```
Category has_many :items
Item belongs_to :category
```

Then to get the count of items for each category, you could do

```
Category.joins(:items).group("category_id").count
```

This will give you a hash with key as category_id and value as the number of items

for eg:

```
{<category_id_1> => 12, <category_id> => 40}
```

You could also group by category_name if you want the key to be the name